# Easy access to entries in set - using where conditions

Tags: java, collections

The class structure is of the following format-

```
class A
{
   Set<B> bHolder;
}

class B
{
   Set<C> cHolder;
}

class C
{
   String data;
}
```

Goal : To retrieve an entry from class A depending on the data in class C

Eg: get B from aObject.bHolder.cHolder.data = "compareString"

Is there any way to do it without completely through the sets?

Thx
-Kiru

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you want to do. What do you mean by "retrieve an entry from class A"?

Comment: retrieve an entry from the Set<B> bHolder in Class A, which contains the class C object with the given data

Comment: "Is there any way to do it without completely through the sets?" Could you explain why this is a problem? It is quite likely this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not when you've just got sets, no. If you want to perform some sort of lookup, you need a collection which supports lookups, such as `HashMap` (or a `Map` in general).